# A Fun, Fantastic, Phonic Cipher!

Tags: cipher, computer-puzzle

An old friend of mine recently sent me an email. Being a linguist, he always finds creative (read: annoying) ways to use his words to baffle me. After about five minutes, I usually just give up. However, recently I discovered about this fantastic website! Here's the email:

```
> aych ee ell ell oh!

>> ay why see aych space oh aych space dee you bee bee ell ee why oh you space ess pea ay see ee space ay why space ay arr arr space ee ee space ess pea ay see ee space dubbleyou aych why space oh aych space why oh you space ess pea ay see ee space dee ee ee space oh aych space ee why ee space ee en space gee ee ee?

>>> ee ee space dubbleyou aych why space ee ee space ess pea ay see ee space ee ess ess space pea ee ay space ay why space ess ee ee space ee ee space ess pea ay see ee space jay ay why space ay why space dubbleyou aych why space ess pea ay see ee space dubbleyou aych why space oh aych space why oh you space ess pea ay see ee space ee ee space ee ess ess space ee ess ess space ess pea ay see ee space tee ee ee space ee ee space ee ee space ess pea ay see ee space ee ess ess space pea ee ay space ay why space ess ee ee space ee ee space ess pea ay see ee space ee ee space ee ef space ess pea ay see ee space ee ee space ee ell ell space ee ell ell space ess pea ay see ee space ee ee space ee ee space ess pea ay see ee space dee ee ee space why oh you space bee ee ee space bee ee ee space ee ell ell space ee ee space dubbleyou aych why space oh aych space why oh you space ess pea ay see ee space ee ess ess space pea ee ay space ay why space ess ee ee space ee ee space ess pea ay see ee space ee ee space dubbleyou aych why space ee ee space ess pea ay see ee space ee ee space ee en space ess pea ay see ee space ee ess ess space pea ee ay space ay why space ess ee ee space ee ee space ess pea ay see ee space tee ee ee space ee ee space ee ee space ess pea ay see ee space oh aych space ay why see aych space ess pea ay see ee space ee ess ess space pea ee ay space ay why space ess ee ee space ee ee space ess pea ay see ee space dee you bee bee ell ee why oh you space ay why see aych space dubbleyou aych why space ess pea ay see ee space oh aych space ay why see aych space ess pea ay see ee space dubbleyou aych why space oh aych space why oh you space ess pea ay see ee space ay why space ay arr arr space ay arr arr space ess pea ay see ee space ee ess ess space pea ee ay space ay why space ess ee ee space ee ee space ess pea ay see ee space ee ess ess space ee ee space ee ee space ess pea ay see ee space ee ee space dubbleyou aych why space ee ee space ess pea ay see ee space tee ee ee space ee ee space ee ee space ess pea ay see ee space dee you bee bee ell ee why oh you space ay why see aych space dubbleyou aych why!

>>>> bee ee ee space ee ee space ee ee space ess pea ay see ee space ee ee space ee ee space ess pea ay see ee space ee ee space ee ee space ess pea ay see ee space ee ess ess space pea ee ay space ay why space ess ee ee space ee ee space ess pea ay see ee space ee ee space ee ee space ess pea ay see ee space ee ee space ee ee space ess pea ay see ee space ee ess ess space pea ee ay space ay why space ess ee ee space ee ee space ess pea ay see ee space ee ee space ee ee space ess pea ay see ee space ee ee space ee ee space ess pea ay see ee space ee ess ess space pea ee ay space ay why space ess ee ee space ee ee space ess pea ay see ee space ee ee space ee ee space ess pea ay see ee space ee ee space ee en space ess pea ay see ee space ee ess ess space pea ee ay space ay why space ess ee ee space ee ee space ess pea ay see ee space ee ee space ee ess ess space ee ess ess space ess pea ay see ee space pea ee ay space ee ee space ay why space ess pea ay see ee space ay why space dubbleyou aych why space ess pea ay see ee space ee ess ess space ee ee space ee ee space ess pea ay see ee space ee ee space ee ee space ess pea ay see ee space ee ess ess space pea ee ay space ay why space ess ee ee space ee ee space ess pea ay see ee space ee ee space ee ee space ess pea ay see ee space ee ee space ee ess ess space ee ess ess space ess pea ay see ee space ee ee space ee ess ess space ee ess ess space ess pea ay see ee space ee ess ess space pea ee ay space ay why space ess ee ee space ee ee space ess pea ay see ee space oh aych space ay why see aych space ess pea ay see ee space ay why space dubbleyou aych why space ess ee ee space ay why see aych space ess pea ay see ee space ee ess ess space pea ee ay space ay why space ess ee ee space ee ee space ess pea ay see ee space ee ee space ee ess ess space ee ess ess space ess pea ay see ee space pea ee ay space ee ee space ay why space ess pea ay see ee space ay why space dubbleyou aych why space ess pea ay see ee space ee ess ess space ee ee space ee ee space ess pea ay see ee space ee ee space ee ee space ess pea ay see ee space ee ess ess space pea ee ay space ay why space ess ee ee space ee ee space ess pea ay see ee space ee ee space ee ee space ess pea ay see ee space ee ee space ee ell ell space ee ell ell space ess pea ay see ee space ee ee space ee ell ell space ee ell ell space ess pea ay see ee space ee ess ess space pea ee ay space ay why space ess ee ee space ee ee space ess pea ay see ee space oh aych space ay why see aych space ess pea ay see ee space ay why space dubbleyou aych why space ess ee ee space ay why see aych space ess pea ay see ee space ee ess ess space pea ee ay space ay why space ess ee ee space ee ee space ess pea ay see ee space ee ee space ee ee space ess pea ay see ee space ee ee space ee en space ess pea ay see ee space ee ess ess space pea ee ay space ay why space ess ee ee space ee ee space ess pea ay see ee space gee ee ee space ee ee space ee ee space ess pea ay see ee space ee ee space ee ee space ess pea ay see ee space ee ee space ee ee space ess pea ay see ee space ee ess ess space pea ee ay space ay why space ess ee ee space ee ee space ess pea ay see ee space ee ee space ee ess ess space ee ess ess space ess pea ay see ee space pea ee ay space ee ee space ay why space ess pea ay see ee space ay why space dubbleyou aych why space ess pea ay see ee space ee ess ess space ee ee space ee ee space ess pea ay see ee space ee ee space ee ee space ess pea ay see ee space ee ess ess space pea ee ay space ay why space ess ee ee space ee ee space ess pea ay see ee space ee ee space ee ee space ess pea ay see ee space ee ee space ee ess ess space ee ess ess space ess pea ay see ee space ee ee space ee ess ess space ee ess ess space ess pea ay see ee space ee ess ess space pea ee ay space ay why space ess ee ee space ee ee space ess pea ay see ee space ee ee space ee ee space ess pea ay see ee space dee you bee bee ell ee why oh you space ay why see aych space dubbleyou aych why space ess pea ay see ee space ee ee space ee ee space ess pea ay see ee space ee ess ess space pea ee ay space ay why space ess ee ee space ee ee space ess pea ay see ee space ee ee space ee ee space ess pea ay see ee space ee ee space ee en space ess pea ay see ee space ee ess ess space pea ee ay space ay why space ess ee ee space ee ee space ess pea ay see ee space ee ee space ee ess ess space ee ess ess space ess pea ay see ee space ee ee space ee ee space ess pea ay see ee space ee ee space ee ee space ess pea ay see ee space ee ess ess space pea ee ay space ay why space ess ee ee space ee ee space ess pea ay see ee space ee ee space ee ee space ess pea ay see ee space ee ee space ee ee space ess pea ay see ee space ee ess ess space pea ee ay space ay why space ess ee ee space ee ee space ess pea ay see ee space ee ee space ee ess ess space ee ess ess space ess pea ay see ee space pea ee ay space ee ee space ay why space ess pea ay see ee space ay why space dubbleyou aych why space ess pea ay see ee space ee ess ess space ee ee space ee ee space ess pea ay see ee space ee ee space ee ee space ess pea ay see ee space ee ess ess space pea ee ay space ay why space ess ee ee space ee ee space ess pea ay see ee space ee ee space ee ee space ess pea ay see ee space dee you bee bee ell ee why oh you space ay why see aych space dubbleyou aych why space ess pea ay see ee space ee ee space ee ee space ess pea ay see ee space ee ess ess space pea ee ay space ay why space ess ee ee space ee ee space ess pea ay see ee space ee ee space ee ess ess space ee ess ess space ess pea ay see ee space pea ee ay space ee ee space ay why space ess pea ay see ee space ay why space dubbleyou aych why space ess pea ay see ee space ee ess ess space ee ee space ee ee space ess pea ay see ee space ee ee space ee ee space ess pea ay see ee space ee ess ess space pea ee ay space ay why space ess ee ee space ee ee space ess pea ay see ee space ay why space dubbleyou aych why space ess pea ay see ee space dee you bee bee ell ee why oh you space ay why see aych space dubbleyou aych why space ess pea ay see ee space ee ess ess space ee ee space ee ee space ess pea ay see ee space ay why space dubbleyou aych why space ess ee ee space ay why see aych space ess pea ay see ee space ee ess ess space pea ee ay space ay why space ess ee ee space ee ee space ess pea ay see ee space ay why space dubbleyou aych why space ess pea ay see ee space dee you bee bee ell ee why oh you space ay why see aych space dubbleyou aych why space ess pea ay see ee space ee ess ess space pea ee ay space ay why space ess ee ee space ee ee space ess pea ay see ee space vee ee ee space ee ee space ee ee space ess pea ay see ee space ee ee space ee ee space ess pea ay see ee space ee ee space ee ee space ess pea ay see ee space ee ess ess space pea ee ay space ay why space ess ee ee space ee ee space ess pea ay see ee space ee ee space ee ee space ess pea ay see ee space ee ee space ee ee space ess pea ay see ee space ee ess ess space pea ee ay space ay why space ess ee ee space ee ee space ess pea ay see ee space ee ee space ee ess ess space ee ess ess space ess pea ay see ee space pea ee ay space ee ee space ay why space ess pea ay see ee space ay why space dubbleyou aych why space ess pea ay see ee space ee ess ess space ee ee space ee ee space ess pea ay see ee space ee ee space ee ee space ess pea ay see ee space ee ess ess space pea ee ay space ay why space ess ee ee space ee ee space ess pea ay see ee space ee ee space ee ee space ess pea ay see ee space ee ee space ee ess ess space ee ess ess space ess pea ay see ee space ee ee space ee ess ess space ee ess ess space ess pea ay see ee space ee ess ess space pea ee ay space ay why space ess ee ee space ee ee space ess pea ay see ee space ee ee space ee ee space ess pea ay see ee space ee ee space ee ee space ess pea ay see ee space ee ess ess space pea ee ay space ay why space ess ee ee space ee ee space ess pea ay see ee space ee ee space ee ee space ess pea ay see ee space ee ee space ee ee space ess pea ay see ee space ee ess ess space pea ee ay space ay why space ess ee ee space ee ee space ess pea ay see ee space ee ee space ee ee space ess pea ay see ee space ee ee space ee en space ess pea ay see ee space ee ess ess space pea ee ay space ay why space ess ee ee space ee ee space ess pea ay see ee space ee ee space ee ess ess space ee ess ess space ess pea ay see ee space pea ee ay space ee ee space ay why space ess pea ay see ee space ay why space dubbleyou aych why space ess pea ay see ee space ee ess ess space ee ee space ee ee space ess pea ay see ee space ee ee space ee ee space ess pea ay see ee space ee ess ess space pea ee ay space ay why space ess ee ee space ee ee space ess pea ay see ee space dee ee ee space why oh you space bee ee ee space bee ee ee space ee ell ell space ee ee space dubbleyou aych why space oh aych space why oh you space ess pea ay see ee space ay why space dubbleyou aych why space ess ee ee space ay why see aych space ess pea ay see ee space dee you bee bee ell ee why oh you space ay why see aych space dubbleyou aych why space ess pea ay see ee space ee ess ess space pea ee ay space ay why space ess ee ee space ee ee space ess pea ay see ee space oh aych space ay why see aych space ess pea ay see ee space ay why space dubbleyou aych why space ess ee ee space ay why see aych space ess pea ay see ee space ee ess ess space pea ee ay space ay why space ess ee ee space ee ee space ess pea ay see ee space dee you bee bee ell ee why oh you space ay why see aych space dubbleyou aych why space ess pea ay see ee space oh aych space ay why see aych space ess pea ay see ee space dubbleyou aych why space oh aych space why oh you...
```

There is more to the email, but it was too long for SE to handle. So [here's a pastebin with the rest.](https://pastebin.com/gJjh3XAL)

Good luck!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a long time and effort:

> I wrote a python script to solve this for me

These are the answers I got:

> hello
>  how are you doing
>  been so long since i have seen you
>  i just flew in to your city
>  i thought we should meet up
>  how about some coffee sooe
>  bye
>  ps along with your answer please post how you decoded the messages  now you might see why the computerpuzzle tag was included  good job

Comment: Good job, you got some of the lines. However, there are 8 in total. Keep searching!

Comment: @yummypasta fixed

Comment: Just for the sake of practice I also ended up writing something in Python. WOW ... this is a load of work and I only did the part in the pastebin. But hey, now I'm better with Python and parsing text in general. :)

Answer (score 2):

1

> hello

2

> aych oh dubbleyou space ay arr ee space why oh you space dee oh eye en gee

⠀

> how are you doing

3

> ee why ee space ess pea ay see ee space jay ay why space why oh you space ee ess ess space tee ee ee space ess pea ay see ee space ee ef space ee ell ell space ee ee space dee you bee bee ell ee why oh you space ess pea ay see ee space ee why ee space ee en space ess pea ay see ee space tee ee ee space oh aych space ess pea ay see ee space ess ee ee space ee why ee space tee ee ee space dubbleyou aych why!

⠀

> eye space jay you ess tee space ef ell ee dubbleyou space eye en space tee oh space see eye tee why

⠀

> I just flew in to city

⠀
I lost my place at one point and I think I missed the word the somewhere, I also don't really want to do the 4th to be honest.

Comment: Good job, you got a portion of the puzzle. Keep decoding! (also, could you please edit to spoiler everything?)